# Golangでパスワードを入力せずにsudoでコマンドを実行する

Tags: bash, go

Golangでsudoでコマンドを実行するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?
Pythonなどの他の言語では

```
os.system("echo 'mypassword' | sudo -S command")
```

とすれば
実行できますがGolangではどのようにすれば良いのでしょうか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec.Command`を使用します。

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("sudo", "-S", "command")
    cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader("mypassword" + "\n")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```